# Cisco - Changing LACP rate from slow to fast

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands

Do you know if any outage is expected or any blip in service when changing LACP rate to fast from slow?

```
interface x/x
lacp rate fast
```

Any experience or info would be appreciated

Thanks

Luke

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer for you as I don't have any hardware handy, but given that lacp rate really only affects the rate of keepalives (every second in fast mode, rather than every 30s), and not some fundamental phys- or link-layer parameter that would require resetting the link, I would hope you can change it without any impact whatsoever on the link state.

Comment: Yep my thoughts exactly - unfortunately GNS doesnt support LACP so cant test and also dont have any hardware handy at the moment either.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

Based on my tests changing the LACP rate bounces the Port-Channel:

```
*Jan  6 04:08:08.204: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/15, changed state to down

*Jan  6 04:08:08.221: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Port-channel16, changed state to down
```